# How to parse "get done doing something"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have read the following sentence from *Diary of a Wimpy Kid 1*.

> After I ***got done mopping*** the floor with Rowley today, I headed
>   home.

I understand this sentence as: *After I finished mopping the floor with Rowley,  I headed home.*

or *I get mopping the floor done with Rowley today, i headed home.*

My question is, how should I parse the structure of this sentence? Is there any likelihood that "I get done" means "I am done", meaning I am going to die? How can I comprehend it correctly?

Comment: Please use proper spacing with the punctuation in your question, and spell out complete words ("something", not "sth"). I've corrected this post for now, but in the future please keep this in mind. Thanks!

Comment: @WendiKidd Thanks for reminding.I will do it next time.

Answer (score 1):

There's no notion of dying in that sentence.
You correctly understood that *get done with something* means to *finish something*, but it also adds a notion of relief as in

> Finally! I'm done with that.